# PHP Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare() Wordpress 3.5 (Updated)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am am getting the error message:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in
>   /home/url.com/wp-content/plugins/WPEC-Personalize-3.8/wpec-personalization.php
>   on line 322 and defined in /home/url.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line
>   990

I have found the code on line 322:

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT enabled FROM ". $table_name ." WHERE pers_id  = ". $myresults->pers_id." AND product_id = ".$product_id));
```

I am trying to update it to the new wordpress (3.5 query) standard:

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT enabled FROM %d WHERE pers_id  = %d AND product_id = %s",$table_name, $myresults->pers_id, $product_id));
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong but when once i updated the code above i stopped getting the error message but every time i update the product it duplicates all the custom fields.

Comment: It's better to just upgrade the plugin. The plugin author should have fixed that anyway.

Comment: The plugin author is not supporting the plugin anymore... :-(

Answer (score 1):

`%s` is used to indicate that the argument is a string, while `%d` is used to indicate a number. In the code posted to your question, these are used incorrectly. Fix them:

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT enabled FROM %s WHERE pers_id = %d AND product_id = %d",
//                       ^^ These are wrong in your posted code ^^
    $table_name,
    $myresults->pers_id,
    $product_id
));
```

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction on how to fix them or to figure out what they should be? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Past this code in your wp-config.php file

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

I also past this code. Now warning message was not displaying.